# Chaining Futures in Scala

Tags: scala, future

Consider this:

`val f1 = Future {}`

`val f2 = Future {}`

`f1.flatMap(_ => f2)`

In this case, is it possible that `f2` completes before `f1` completes ?

I suspect yes.

So how could I fix that ? I mean, how can I make sure that `f2` starts only after `f1` has completed ?

Would this work/(be good style):

`def f1 = Future {}`

`def f2 = Future {}`

`f1.flatMap(_ => f2)`

?

Comment: Why? If `f1` and `f2` are independent futures then what purpose is served by chaining them? If the two futures are not actually independent then the question isn't how to chain them but how to correctly define them to represent their relationship.

Comment: This problem comes up in async scalatest for scalajs.

Comment: jhegedus, your comment didn't clarify jwh's concerns al all (at least for me). You probably should elaborate in more details what is the exact semantics of what you are trying to achieve. It is really hard to help you without knowing the semantics.

Comment: Yeah, `f1` should execute and finish before `f2`, that is their relationship, other than that, they are independent completely. For example, `f1` = I put the glass onto the table, `f2`= I pour the water. Now, here, in this example, you can see that the order matters, right ? I don't want the table to be wet now, do I ? Or for example, this really might help in understanding the semantics (I hope) : `f1` = I take the cow out of the shed and put it to the place where my wife was standing, `f2` = I start to milk the cow. If I don't want bad tasting milk I better make sure that the order is right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As soon as you define a `Future {}` it is started right away, which means when you define f1 and f2 as two futures f1 starts executing and then f2 starts right way.

So any of those can finish first.

See REPL example below when you define `Future` as `val` it is executed right away.

```
scala> import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.Future

scala> import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

scala> val f1 = Future { Thread.sleep(5000); println("f1 finished")}
f1: scala.concurrent.Future[Unit] = Future(<not completed>)

scala> val f2 = Future { println("f2 finished")}
f2 finished
f2: scala.concurrent.Future[Unit] = Future(<not completed>)

scala> f1 finished
```

**you can use for comprehension to make sure f1 starts first,**. for comprehension itself is expanded to `flatMap`

```
scala> for { f1 <- Future { Thread.sleep(5000); println("f1 started"); 100}
     |       f2 <- Future { println("f2 started"); 200 }
     | } yield (f1, f2)
res1: scala.concurrent.Future[(Int, Int)] = Future(<not completed>)

scala> f1 started
f2 started
```

**Or even within your example, you can use inline Futures instead of evaluated variables.**

```
scala> Future { Thread.sleep(5000); println("f1 finished")}.flatMap {f => Future {println("f2 started"); 200}} 
res2: scala.concurrent.Future[Int] = Future(<not completed>)

scala> f1 finished
f2 started
```

**And the best way is to use functions,**

```
scala> def f1 = Future { Thread.sleep(5000); println("f1 finished")}
f1: scala.concurrent.Future[Unit]

scala> def f2 = Future {println("f2 started"); 200}
f2: scala.concurrent.Future[Int]

scala> f1.flatMap(_ => f2)
res3: scala.concurrent.Future[Int] = Future(<not completed>)

scala> f1 finished
f2 started
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace val with def, basically instant compute to lazy compute.

```
def f1 = Future {}
def f2 = Future {}

f1.flatMap(_ => f2)
```